# PowerShell Try, Catch, custom terminating error message

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Is there a way to customize the error message of a terminating error?

In the example below I would like to just end up with one `Try` section and collect all errors in one `Catch` section by combining both script blocks. My problem is that the `$error` generated by `Import-csv` is not descriptive enough and I would like to have the text `Failed CSV-File import c:\test.csv` within the `$error` message.

Thank you for your advise.

**Script block 1**

```
Try {
    $File = (Import-Csv -Path c:\test.csv)
}
Catch {
    throw $error[0].Exception.Message | Send-Mail $ScriptAdmin "FAILED CSV-File import"
}
```

**Script block 2**

```
try {
    if(!(Test-Path $LogFolder -PathType Container)) {throw "Can't find the log folder: '$LogFolder'"}
    $Credentials = Import-Credentials $UserName $PasswordFile
}
catch {
    throw $Error[0].Exception.Message | Send-Mail $ScriptAdmin "FAILURE"
}
```

**Workaround**

A possible solution would be to check first with `test-path` if the import file exists and then create a `throw` with a customized message. But I would like to know if it's possible to handle it in one line of code without using `test-path` first.

**Best solution (thanks to mjolinor):**

```
try {
    $File = (Import-Csv -Path $ImportFile -Header "A", "B", "C", "D" | Where { $_.A -NotLike "#*" })
    if(!(Test-Path $LogFolder -PathType Container)) {throw "Can't find the log folder: '$LogFolder'"}
    $Credentials = Import-Credentials $UserName $PasswordFile
}
catch {
    Switch -Wildcard ($Error[0].Exception)
        {
           "*$ImportFile*"
           { $FailType = "FAILED CSV-File import" }

           "*$LogFolder*"
           { $FailType = "FAILED Log folder not found" }

           "*Import-Credentials*"
           { $FailType = "FAILED Credential import" }

           Default
           { $FailType = "FAILED Unrecognized error" }

         }
       Write-Warning $Error[0].Exception.Message
       throw $Error[0].Exception.Message | Send-Mail $ScriptAdmin $FailType
}
```

- Make sure that your `advanced-function` which you created (like Import-Credentials above) contains the function name in the `throw` section. So we can filter it out in the `catch`block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Try {
      $File = (Import-Csv -Path c:\test.csv)

      if(!(Test-Path $LogFolder -PathType Container)) 
      { throw "Can't find the log folder: '$LogFolder'" }

      $Credentials = Import-Credentials $UserName $PasswordFile

      }

catch {
        Switch -Wildcard ($Error[0].CategoryInfo)
        {
           '*[Import-CSV]*' 
           { $FailType = 'Import CSV failed' }

           '*[Test-Path]*'
           { $FailType = 'LogFolder not found' }

           '*[Import-Credentials]*'
           { $FailType = 'Credential import failed' }

           Default
           { $FailType = 'Unrecognized error' }

         }

         $Error[0].Exception.Message | Send-Mail $ScriptAdmin $FailType

       }
```

Edit (for some reason I'm not able to post a comment):

I should have specified that it wasn't tested, and was intended more as a pattern than a finished solution, and it seems to have done what it was intended to do.

@BartekB - I habitually use $Error[0] instead of $_ because it seems more explicit and  intuitive to read, and less likely to be misunderstood by someone less experienced who might inherit the code later.

Comment: Thank you mjolinor, that's exactly what I'm looking for. However, it errors out with `The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: *[Import-CSV]*` although `$error[0] contains the matching word: ` + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Works like a charm when removing the brackets [], from `'*[Import-CSV]*'` to `'*Import-CSV*'`. Thanks again, this helped me a lot :)

Comment: For `Test-Path` this doesn't work, because the field `$Error[0].CategoryInfo`doesn't contain the word `Test-Path` as it's not in the `throw`. Is there a way to set the `CategoryInfo` from within `throw`?

Comment: Found it, the best way to do it (thanks to your help) is using `$Error[0].Exception` and then put the variables used as wildcards, like `*$ImportFile*` and `*$LogFolder*` and others. I'll mark your answer as `Solved`. Thanks again :) I'll update the post with the full solution to for others.

Comment: BTW: any reason why you use `$Error[0]` instead of `$_`? Latter (by definition) should contain thrown error.