# PowerShell Try/Catch with If Statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement, error-handling, try-catch

#### Problem/Details

I am working in PowerShell and trying to figure out how custom Try Catch statements work. My current major issue involves mixing Try/Catch and If statements. So the idea of what I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
try {
    if (!$someVariable.Text) { throw new exception 0 }
    elseif ($someVariable.Text -lt 11) { throw new exception 1 }
    elseif (!($someVariable.Text -match '[a-zA-Z\s]')) { throw new exception 2}
}
catch 0 {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Custom Error Message 1")
}
catch 1 {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Custom Error Message 2")
}
catch 2 {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Custom Error Message 3")
}
```

Now I know the above code is very inaccurate in terms of what the actual code will be, but I wanted to visually display what I'm thinking and trying to achieve.

#### Question

Does anyone know how to create custom error messages with PowerShell that could assist me with achieving something close to the above idea and explain your answer a bit? Thank you in advance

So far, the link below is the closest thing I have found to what I'm trying to achieve:

[PowerShell Try, Catch, custom terminating error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970528/powershell-try-catch-custom-terminating-error-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Error you throw is stored at $_.Exception.Message

```
$a = 1
try{
    If($a -eq 1){
        throw "1"
    }
}catch{
    if ($_.Exception.Message -eq 1){
        "Error 1"
    }else{
        $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I get it now. So I can simply use `throw` and append anything I want in `" "` and then when I do my catch statement... I can then parse through those with either an if or a switch. Perfect, perfect. Thank you. I don't know how I wasn't getting that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `$PSCmdlet` `ThrowTerminatingError()` method.  Here's an example:

```
Function New-ErrorRecord
{
    param(
        [String]$Exception,
        [String]$ExceptionMessage,
        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory] $ErrorCategory,
        [String] $TargetObject
    )

    $e = New-Object $Exception $ExceptionMessage
    $errorRecord = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord $e, $ErrorID, $ErrorCategory, $TargetObject
    return $ErrorRecord
}

Try
{
If (not condition)
{
    $Error = @{
      Exception = 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException'
      ExceptionMessage = 'Error text here'
      ErrorCategory = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidArgument
      TargetObject = ''
    }
    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError((New-ErrorRecord @Error))
}
} Catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException]
{
    'do stuff'
}
```

Comment: I will file this away for a later use. But for now, the simple answer provided by @ArcSet has proven to be very helpful